# adding features on WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: jax-ws, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to download the JAX-WS feature on WSO2 Identity server and skip the following problem:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - JAX-WS/JAX-RS Webapp Management Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.jaxws.webapp.mgt.feature.group 4.2.0) Software currently installed: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.11 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.4.11) Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.2.0) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.1) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.2 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.2) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.3 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.3) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.4 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.4) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.7 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.7) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.8 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.8) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.9 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.9) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.11 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.11) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.14 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.14) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar [4.2.0] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.11 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.4.11) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar [4.4.11] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - JAX-WS/JAX-RS Webapp Management Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.jaxws.webapp.mgt.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group [4.2.0,4.3.0)

My version of WSO2 is 5.3.0, the version of Carbon is 4.4.11 and the library I am using is this: http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/turing/
I have also tested the feature of this repository: http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/
But it is impossible and I can not get it installed.